# What's the meaning of metered wifi networks?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

Ok , I know that means this wifi network is a cost wifi. and it will make apps won't use any data when in background . but it's tip is : Apps may warn before using these networks for large downloads.

Whatever I download, it seems never show that warning .

could anyone give me a screen shot about this warning?[image]

Comment: it is down to the applications own settings that it may give you a warning or not. Usually stores like play store will detect your connection and display a warning if you are on cellular networks and you are trying to download a large file above the set threshold limit. metered networks may be treated as a regular WiFi connection and application will not warn you before you start your download

Comment: Does it means the warning totally depends on which App you use , and the system will not show this warning? Wow if App doesn't show any notice we will bankrupt... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your device settings state if the background data is NOT restricted system treats metered networks as regular WiFi connections.

in this case; "you will not receive any warnings prior to any downloads from any store downloading any application or any file"

However if the background data IS restricted metered networks are treated as cellular networks and you will get warnings given that you are using an application which has that capability!

If you go to a browser from you mobile device and download a big file you will most likely see no warnings unless your device has some software monitoring for this kind of events

Android operating system provides this through mobile data monitor as well as some other functionalities like setting caps. But if you are under your monthly limit don't have any other restrictions setup it will not warn you that you are about to download a big file.

Coming back to what i said before its down to the application you use to download files that you get a warning or not ultimately